# $M \not \models \phi$ vs $M \models \neg \phi$

Tags: first-order-logic

Let $\phi$ be a First Order formula. If $M \not\models \phi$ does it mean that $M \models \neg \phi$? Why?

Comment: We can't have $M \models \phi$ and $M \models \neg \phi$ for models of first-order logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If $M$ is a structure, then "$M\models\neg\varphi$" means *by definition* "$M\not\models\varphi$."

However, note that things get more complicated at the level of **theories**. A theory $\Gamma$ - that is, a set of sentences - is said to satisfy a sentence $\varphi$ if $\varphi$ is true whenever $\Gamma$ is true; that is, $$\mbox{for all structures $M$, if $M\models\Gamma$ then $M\models\varphi$.}$$ (Here "$M\models\Gamma$" is shorthand for "$M\models\psi$ for every $\psi\in\Gamma$.") If $\Gamma$ satisfies $\varphi$, we write (perhaps confusingly) "$\Gamma\models\varphi$."

Now it is **no longer true** that "$\models\neg$" is the same as "$\not\models$"! This is because *theories don't have to decide everything*, whereas models do. For example, if we take $\Gamma$ to be the set of [group axioms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Group_Axioms), and let $\varphi$ be the sentence $\forall x\forall y(x*y=y*x)$, then

- $\Gamma\not\models\varphi$, since there are *nonabelian* groups; but also
- $\Gamma\not\models\neg\varphi$, since there are *abelian* groups.

---

Note: there is nothing special here about first-order logic! Second-order logic, infinitary logic, logic with a cardinality quantifier, etc. also behave the same way. Basically, any logic founded on classical propositional logic (two truth values, excluded middle, etc.) will work this way, since the truth definition for negation will be "$M\models\neg\varphi\iff M\not\models\varphi$". Note that things will be different if we look at logics founded on *intuitionistic* propositional logic, but that's a whole other can of worms.

Comment: It is true in the FO. What about SO?

Comment: @Logic It is also true in SO; the truth definition for SO treats negation *exactly the same as FO*.

Comment: @Logic Remember that the second-order theory of a structure $(M; ...)$ is just the *first-order* theory of the "power-structure" of $M$: the structure with domain $M$ + all relations on $M$, and language that of $M$ together with an $n$-ary "element of" relation for each $n$. So in particular, second-order logic treats Booleans identically to how first-order logic does. For instance, in [these notes](http://phil.elte.hu/mekis/sol.pdf) when the semantics for SO is given, Booleans are completely ignored since they're unchanged from FO; I think that's sloppy, but that's the reason for it.

Comment: thanks :)
Could you look at? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132397/compactness-theorem-a-challenging-task